# XSLT - Check if certain element or nodes exist

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Ive been googling ways to try to do the below and am getting a few hits, hoever, none are working for me.

I have incoming XMLs that be either of the 2 XMLs.

```
<Session>
      <SessionID>1231</SessionID>
      <ClientID>556677</ClientID>
</Session>
```

or

```
<Session>
      <SessionID>1231</SessionID>
      <CompanyID>1060</CompanyID>
</Session>
```

Based on the above, the XML can very from CompanyId to ClientId. I want to transform he XML but order to do this I need a way to say:

If I get ClientID, then only get the value and transform the XML so that is shows up like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sessions xmlns="http://mysite/services/v1">
      <a:Session>1231</a:Session>
      <a:Client>556677</a:Client>
</Sessions>
```

and if I get CompanyID, I transform to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Sessions xmlns="http://mysite/services/v1">
          <a:Session>1231</a:Session>
          <a:Company>1060</a:Company>
    </Sessions>
```

The XML will come with either element CLientID or element with CompanyID but not both....

I have tried to use the following with no success:

```
<xsl:choose> 
 <xsl:when test="/Session/ClientID"> 
<a:Client>
 <xsl:value-of select="a:Session/a:ClientId"/>
  </a:Client>
 </xsl:choose>
```

I want to be able to check if an element with "ClientID" is on the XML, I can get the value from it and create an element called" Client"...same scenario if I get an XML with Company.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your result is not valid: the prefix "a" is not bound to a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="www.sample_namespace.com"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Session">
    <xsl:element name="Sessions" namespace="http://mysite/services/v1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SessionID">
    <a:Session><xsl:apply-templates/></a:Session>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ClientID">
    <a:Client><xsl:apply-templates/></a:Client>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CompanyID">
    <a:Company><xsl:apply-templates/></a:Company>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When tried with your sample XML above:

```
<Session>
    <SessionID>1231</SessionID>
    <CompanyID>1060</CompanyID>
</Session>
```

Produces the result:

```
<Sessions xmlns="http://mysite/services/v1">
    <a:Session xmlns:a="www.sample_namespace.com">1231</a:Session>
    <a:Company xmlns:a="www.sample_namespace.com">1060</a:Company>
</Sessions>
```